# How to retrieve documents from cloud firestore from a parent collection with attribute matches/or no matches from subcollection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a cloud firestore setup like this -

/questions/{qid}/attempts/{attemptId}

The structure of the question document and attempt document is like below -

```
questionID
  questionText: "QuestionText"
  Options: ['option1','option2']
  class: [1,2]
  subject: science
  ...

attemptdId
 questionID: <qid>
 numAttempts: 5
 correctAttempts: 2
 uid:uid
 lastAttemptIsCorrect:true/false
 ...
```

For each question,served to the user the attempt is stored in the sub collection attempts document - only 1 attempt document per question per user is stored, each attempt of same question updates the existing attempt document.

I want to retrieve the questions for

1. class:1, subject:science which user has not attempted (no attempts)
2. class:1, subject:science which user has attempted incorrectly in last attempt

How can this be achieved in the current structure ? or can be achieved using a different structure?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I suggest starting with the documentation, make an attempt, then post what isn't working the way you expect.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson for the edits, i am a newbie - and don't have a clue if this is possible in firestore, the documentation also does not have anything like this (or i missed something ?)

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to do #1 at all, since you can't query for things that don't exist in Firestore

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using same structure. Here are suggessted  steps with recommended links:

1. First, query all questions collection using array-contains to filter class followed by subject as example below:

```
    // returns questins that of class 1 and subject science
    questionResults = db.collection('questions`).where('class', 'array-contains', 
      '1').where('subject','==','science').valuesChanges();
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership

2. Now iterate over each questionResults obtained from over ( you to need to subscribe to get the actual response, let me know if you do not  know this).
   For each question of iteration, now retrieve the subcollection `attempts` and
   check if its numAttempts is 0 to find out whether its attempted or not.
   You can get the subcollection  (attempts) doc as:

```
    db.collection('questions').doc('question_uid').collection('attempts').
     doc('attempt_uid')
```

If condition matches , we want to push this question to array. Following is just logic ,not actual code. eg.

```
    desiredQuestionList = [];
    questionResults.forEach(question=>{
      // fetch attempts doc of question
       if (attempt doc has 0 attempts count){
          desiredQuestionList.push(question)
       }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if there are N questions (which you get in questionResults) this approach means making N more calls to check if question is already attempted. Far too many calls to my comfort.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve this with a single query. But you can use [Collection Group Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

Collection Group Queries retrieve data from all collections with the same ID (for example `attempts`). You could then get all attempts for which the last attempt was incorrect:

```
var attempts = db.collectionGroup('attempts').where('lastAttemptIsCorrect', '==', true);
```

You then would have to relate the attempts with the questions with it's questionID.

AFAIK, this is the best approach that's currently supported